# Input validation in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have made form in swing with 6 jTextFields. User should be able to input only numbers from 1 to 48 in each of Text fields. There should be also check to see if any of numbers repeat and app should check if any field is left blank.

I know how to do this in VB.net but i'm new to java in general.

In VB.net i would put all textfields in array and then check to see if all text fields are filled in, are the numbers in range and check if there is a duplicate number in any field. If all criteria is met i would proceed to send inputs to database.

I am fairly new to java so if anyone could help me or point me in right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: first of all, what input field are you using, JTextfield?

Comment: I am using jTextFields, thank you

Answer (score 5):

There a number of ways that this might be achieved depending on how you want to achieve it...

### You Could...

Use a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), this will  validate the user inpur when the field is actioned or focus is lost, discard, what it considers to be, invalid input.

This is good for post validation of most common formats but does lack some flexibility...

### You Could...

Use a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html), this will validate the user input after the field is actioned or focus is lost.  This is good when you want to allow the user to quickly move between values without the need to actually type something (click up or down is much easier the selecting the field, moving to the right, deleting the last character and incrementing the value by one...for example :P)

### You Could...

Use a [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) to perform your own validation and take appropriate steps based on your needs.

Technically, you could use this with the other solutions, but it might effect how `JFormattedField` and `JSpinner` work, so be careful.

This provides you with the ability to define the actual rules used to post validate the field when it is actioned or focus is lost.  It also allows you to decide how focus transversal should work when the field is invalid, allowing to maintain focus on the field until the value is valid if you want.

You could also display an error message here as well...

### You Could...

Use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter), which would allow you to do real time valildation of the input as the user makes it, discard invalid characters in real time.

This is one of the most complex solutions, but can also be one of the most useful.

For examples see [MDP's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20170730154818/http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) (archived).

Answer (score 0):

1. retrieve text from textfield via [getText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29);
2. parse via [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), if it throws an exception, then the input was not valid
3. verify numbers are in range
4. add them all to a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and check to see if its size is 6. If not then there were duplicates.

Here's an example of what the validation could look like:

```
JTextField[] fields;

void vaildate() {//call when appropriate(ie ActionListener of JButton)
    int[] nums = new int[fields.length];
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        try {
            nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(fields[i].getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            //not a valid number tell user of error
            return;
        }
        if (nums[i] < 1 || nums[i] > 48) {
            //out of number range tell user of error
            return;
        }
        if (!set.add(nums[i])) {
            //duplicate element tell user of error
            return;
        }
    }
    //do what you want with the data now
}
```

Comment: I know in theory how it's meant to be done. But as I said i have little experience with java in general so a little example would be nice.

Comment: Dude, you're a gem. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Note that if your database interaction is going to take a noticeable amount of time, and you do it in the body of the validate, the whole ui will freeze for that time. To fix this you'll need to use a [separate thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), but this may be too complex for your needs.

Comment: I have managed to set up socket communication so I will be sending already validated data to server. So i think this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();


do{
   int number = Interger.parseInterger(field.getText()); // this is how you will parse it into int

   if (number < 1 || number is > 48){
    System.Out.Println("Error, try again");
}

}while(number > 0 || number is < 49)
```

Comment: and you also need to parse it into integer like vandale said.

Comment: Wow, this won't block the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing the user from ever been able to respond to the error...